# TeX Live 2013 tlmgr fails when trying to update -- TeX Live 2013 frozen

Tags: texlive

When running `tlmgr updateerror all` (with TeX Live 2013 distribution) in Windows OS, I get the following message:

```
TeX Live 2013 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

If you're interested in helping to pretest the new release (when
pretests are available), please read http://tug.org/texlive/pretest.html.
Otherwise, just wait, and the new release will be ready in due time.
tlmgr.pl: package repository http://ctan.imsc.res.in/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to C:/texlive/2013/tlpkg/backups

tlmgr: all mentioned, but neither new nor forcibly removed
tlmgr: no updates available
```

What should I do?

Comment: Nothing; wait for TeX Live 2014. There will simply be no more updates to TeX Live 2013.

Comment: I updated some days ago last time, it worked then, but now it seems to be closed. Try to obtain some packages manually

Comment: Please try to make question titles a little more descriptive. “TeXLive 2013 tlmgr” could ask about virtually anything: What is it? It’s broken, how to fix it? How to use it? ...

Comment: Not related to the question here (I'll delete this comment shortly). I wanted to thank you for uploading the image to my answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173973/3954. However, I initially forgot part of the code in the answer and the image wasn't showing the real result. Now I've corrected the code, but unfortunately the image no longer reflected the result of the code, so I had to delete it. Thanks again for having added it :)

Comment: No mention @GonzaloMedina. It was my pleasure to help