# Distorted caption in listings

Tags: listings, captions, subfloats

The following code produces strange results. Everything looks fine, if I don't include the `subfig` package or don't use the `xleftmargin` parameter. It also works if I use `captionpos=t`. Is there a workaround for this problem? I have to use `subfig`, `xleftmargin` and `captionpos=b`. I am using TexLive 2013 with all updates installed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   captionpos=b,
   numbers=left,
   xleftmargin=20em
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={information information information information information information information}]
A = B
C = D
\end{lstlisting}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `xleftmargin=20em`?

Comment: @Jubobs: This is just to illustrate the problem. I set ´xleftmargin=2em´ to print line numbers not in the text margin.

Comment: Well, if I set `xleftmargin=2em`, I don't see anything wrong with the caption... A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: If you just need `subfig` but don't need the features from the `caption` package, load `subfig` with the `caption=false` option as in `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`.

Comment: @Jucobs: There is another problem with hyphenation (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173767/hyphenation-in-listings-captions-doesnt-work-correctly) and it looks weird if the hyphen is not at the end of the line.

Comment: Perhaps the solution in [How to center a listing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5818) might help.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think you should make that an answer `:)`

Comment: @Jubobs Done! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need `subfig` but don't need the features from the `caption` package, which is the real responsible of this behaviour, load `subfig` with the `caption=false` option as in

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

A complete example with your code in which I've also included the change in \pretolerance suggested by **Herbert** in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173779/3954) to [Hyphenation in listings captions doesn't work correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173767/3954):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   captionpos=b,
   numbers=left,
   xleftmargin=20em
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\pretolerance=100 information information information information information information information}]
A = B
C = D
\end{lstlisting}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but in my real document I also need the caption package which distorted the caption again. Is there a solution for this? I have tried to change the include order but no success... :(